# Conditional Column to Flag for Presence of Any 1 Survey Type at the Customer ID Level (DAX, PowerBI)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a customer fact table similar to the below with a Customer ID and Start Date, then a secondary Survey table that is tied to the fact table on the Customer ID with a one (customer) to many (surveys) relationship.

Customer Table:

| Customer ID | Start Date |
| --- | --- |
| Customer 12 | 1/1/2021 |
| Customer 34 | 1/1/2021 |
| Customer 56 | 1/1/2021 |
| Customer 78 | 1/1/2021 |
| Customer 91 | 1/1/2021 |

Survey Table:

| Customer ID | Survey |
| --- | --- |
| Customer 12 | Survey A |
| Customer 12 | Survey B |
| Customer 34 | Survey C |
| Customer 34 | Survey D |
| Customer 56 | PWI |

Records of customers with surveys will appear in the Surveys table, customers without obviously won't appear there just yet.

My goal is to create a table visual that lists all Customer IDs that do not have a Survey - so, in the above scenario, customers 78 and 91 both do not have surveys yet, but they've been with the company for more than 30 days, so I want to flag these folks.

Then, customer 56 does have a record in the Survey table, but not a record that "counts" in this exercise... so, customer 56 would be flagged as well because he does not have a "Survey 1" OR "Survey 2" OR "Survey 3"... the order doesn't matter, I'm just interested in finding customers who do not have a survey and have been with us for 30 days or more.

Hopefully, that explanation helps -- Appreciate any and all guidance to accomplish this in PBI with conditional columns, maybe merging of tables in PowerQuery or via a DAX measure. I do want to be able to slice this, so a bit of a limitation there maybe.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

```
Flag = 
VAR _days = INT ( TODAY() - SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Customer Table'[Start Date] ) )
VAR _surveys = 
    COUNTROWS ( 
        FILTER ( 'Survey Table' , 
        CONTAINSSTRING ( [Survey] , "survey" ) )
    ) 
RETURN 
IF ( _days > 30 && ISBLANK ( _surveys ) , "Flag" )
```

Gives the following result in a table visual with the `Customer ID` column as values:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do it in M / Powerquery

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="CustomerTable"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Customer ID", type text}, {"Start Date", type date}}),

// calculate length of time as a customer, in days
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "CustomerForDays", each Number.From(Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow())-[Start Date])),

// merge in any customer that also had a survey from SurveyTable query
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(SurveyTable, each Text.Contains([Survey], "Survey")),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Custom",{"Customer ID"},#"Filtered Rows" ,{"Customer ID"},"SurveyTable",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded SurveyTable" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "SurveyTable", {"Survey"}, {"Survey"}),

// filter out survey<>null and keep Customer>=30 days
#"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded SurveyTable", each [Survey] = null and [CustomerForDays] >= 30),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows1",{"CustomerForDays", "Survey"})

in  #"Removed Columns"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. Considering there is Relationship on CustomerId col (one-to-many from customers to survey),I have created a measure that decides based on 2 conditions u have. In sample i modified the start date for customer 34 to 15th Sept 2021.
[image]

```
Flag = 

var days_diff = DATEDIFF(MAX(Customers[Start Date]),NOW(),DAY)
var cust_exists = IF(ISBLANK(MAX(Surveys[customerId])),FALSE(),TRUE())

return IF(AND(cust_exists,days_diff<=30),1,0)
```

Comment: This fails to flag Customer 56.